# Переадрессация при парсинге сайта

Tags: php

Всем привет! Подскажите, пож, пытаюсь парсить страницу сайта

```
    function send_http($url, $ua)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $headers = [
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: ru-RU,en;q=0.5',
        "Host: " . parse_url($url) ["host"],
      'User-Agent: ' . $ua,
    ];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
        exit();
    }


    curl_close($ch);

    return $html;
}

$page = send_http('https://link/', get_ua());
```

Суть в том, что сайт автоматически перенаправляется на link/ua (украинскую версию сайта) и curl забирает именно эту украинскую версию, а мне нужно парсить link. Как  передать команду парсингу, чтобы русскоязычную версию забирал?

Comment: Попробуйте
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у вас явно директива указана для `curl`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);`

Эта директива обязывает следовать `redirect`-заголовкам. Замените на `FALSE` (хотя, можно и удалить - если мне не изменяет память, по умолчанию перенаправление игнорируется и так).

*Пока писал ответ, выше в комментариях написали аналогичное.*

P.S. Игнорировать / удалить cache: добавьте

`curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);`

UPDATE: перенаправление вызывается для определённых UA. Попробуйте так - меня сработало:

```
function send_http($url, $ua)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $headers = [
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
        "Host: " . parse_url($url)["host"],
        'User-Agent: ' . $ua,
        'Cache-Control: no-cache'
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
        exit();
    }


    curl_close($ch);

    return $html;
}

$page = send_http('https://apeiron.school', "curl");
```

Comment: У меня же указан этот параметр

Comment: Укажите тогда явным образом: curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cache-Control: no-cache"));

Comment: C:\Users\qwerty>curl -L -I https://apeiron.school
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2023 19:37:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPFRONTSESSID=d047ae7f797255a6a6fba00f8d99eaab; path=/; domain=.apeiron.school; HttpOnly
x-ray: wn39340:0.020/wa39340:D=28418

Comment: У меня все равно на /uk перекидывает ((

Comment: HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: nginx Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2023 19:47:09 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive x-ray: wn39340:4.030/wa39340:D=4022968 Location: https://apeiron.school/uk HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2023 19:47:10 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: PHPFRONTSESSID=9df1a61b448dc4aca68f2199d06635ce; path=/; domain=.apeiron.school;

Comment: А какая команда? С -L запускаете? Попробуйте curl -H "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store" -I -L https://apeiron.school?somefake.

Comment: Запускаю в php скрипте, у меня в вопросе в самом верху вся эта функция send_http написана

Comment: Если нет возможности с командной строки, попробуйте URL заменить на https://apeiron.school?somefake. Перегрузите сервер свой тоже.

Comment: Открыл страницу https://apeiron.school/ в инкогнито в браузере и вписал https://apeiron.school/?somefake так оно мне переадресовало на https://apeiron.school/uk/?somefake  Пока вручную не выберешь русский язык на сайте, все время перекидывает на /uk. Ничего не понимаю (

Comment: Обновлю ответ скоро

Comment: Бомба. Спасибо огромное